# Why doesn't every square matrix have linearly independent eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So guys,

*A is a n by n matrix*

Lets say $Ax= \lambda x$ where $\lambda$ denotes the eigenvalue. If $\lambda=0$ then $x$ is in the nullspace $N(A)$. If $\lambda \ne 0$ then $x$ is in the column space $C(A)$. Those spaces have dimensions $(n-r)+r=n$

let $r$ denote the rank of the matrix.

**So Why doesn't every square matrix have n linearly independent eigenvectors?**

Comment: And what is $r$, if that is not asking too much :-J

Comment: edited. thanks.

Comment: (expanded a lot) Try studying the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the matrix $\pmatrix{7 & 1\\ 0 & 7\\ }$. You will find that there do not exist $n$ (that is $2$) linearly independent eigenvectors in this case. The reason is that one eigenvalue, $7$, is "repeated" but it is not possible to "repeat" eigenvectors associated to it, without introducing linear dependence. This is different from $\pmatrix{7 & 0\\ 0 & 7\\ }$ where you _can_ get linear independence.

Comment: Your claim _"if $\lambda\ne 0$ then $x$ is in the column space $C(A)$"_ is incorrect.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Actually, it is correct, but the problem is that the converse is false: there are vectors which are in the column space but not eigenvectors or even combinations of eigenvectors.

Comment: @Ian You are so right. If $x$ is an eigenvector such that $Ax=\lambda x$ and furthermore $\lambda\ne 0$, then $x$ has the "representation" $A\left( \frac{1}{\lambda}x \right) = x$ which proves my last comment was wrong. An answer to this question should state your observation that the converse (which is false) is erroneously applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about the $\lambda=0$ or $\lambda\ne 0$ distinction, it's not essential here; let's assume $\lambda\ne 0$, and the matrix is full rank.

If I got you right, your reasoning, applied to this particular case, is this: Given that the dimension of the column space $C(A)$ is $n$ (true) and that the eigenvectors are in the colum space (true), then we should be able to find $n$ LI eigenvectors.

But the conclusion does not follow. The eigenvectors are in the column space, true, but not all vectors in the column space are eigenvectors.

Example : $A=\begin{pmatrix} 2 &1 \\ 0 & 2\end{pmatrix}$ Here the column space is the full space, but the eigenvectors lie on a one-dimensional subspace $x=  (a, 0)^t$